# Listing a file with strange characters on DD-WRT embedded Linux

Tags: embedded, special-characters

When SSHing into my **DD-WRT** router (Buffalo WHR-HP-G54) with **embedded Linux** to browse the DHCP Lease list I get strange characters:

```
~ # more /tmp/udhcpd.leases
x▒_▒▒
     ▒▒iPhone-de-Tomaz▒
                       e▒2▒}'▒▒
                               d▒android-44bb0dfe552c0cc5▒$uR
                                                             '▒
                                                               g)Dess-iPadx@▒▒K▒
                                                                                handroid-2a1b5edae9710beӊ▒n▒▒
                          ▒Gandroid-44fa2b3cf7135ebd▒88▒▒Y▒
                                                           j▒android-52f86ace6acd8137HZ?G:|▒
         k$▒android-607ba415a5ab90e5▒▒▒▒
                                        lLiyanaRnsiPhone▒▒o▒▒S▒
                                                               m@▒▒▒:▒
```

This did not happen with the DD-WRT on Buffalo WHR-HP-GN model, maybe because the file is different:

```
root@Oficina-Buffalo:~# more /tmp/dnsmasq.leases
86400 00:12:3f:cf:e0:b7 192.168.8.135 SuperJ-PC 01:00:12:3f:cf:e0:b7
0 00:1d:73:55:7c:9a 192.168.8.209 AP-9 01:00:1d:73:55:7c:9a
0 00:1d:73:55:7b:bc 192.168.8.208 AP-8 01:00:1d:73:55:7b:bc
0 00:1d:73:55:84:44 192.168.8.207 AP-7 01:00:1d:73:55:84:44
0 00:1d:73:55:f7:26 192.168.8.206 AP-6 01:00:1d:73:55:f7:26
0 00:1d:73:55:7e:aa 192.168.8.205 AP-5 01:00:1d:73:55:7e:aa
0 00:1d:73:de:03:d8 192.168.8.203 AP-3 01:00:1d:73:de:03:d8
0 00:1d:73:55:f8:7e 192.168.8.202 AP-2 01:00:1d:73:55:f8:7e
0 00:1d:73:55:f7:bc 192.168.8.201 AP-1 01:00:1d:73:55:f7:bc
0 00:1d:73:55:f8:00 192.168.8.204 AP-4 01:00:1d:73:55:f8:00
0 00:1d:1a:07:c6:a5 192.168.8.212 Router-OvisLink-Hall 01:00:1d:1a:07:c6:a5
0 00:1e:2a:dc:6b:15 192.168.8.228 APWiFi-NetGear-Hall 01:00:1e:2a:dc:6b:15
86400 00:1f:fe:60:86:40 192.168.8.147 * *
```

Both routers seem to use `udhcpd`.
All I need is to just obtain the number of DHCP Leases at `/tmp/udhcpd.leases`, but these strange characters don't allow me to count the number of lines:

```
~ # cat /tmp/udhcpd.leases | wc -l
0
```

How could I **"clean"** this strange file, or at least **count** the number of lines (that will correspond to the number of DHCP leases)?

As usual on routers (DD-WRT for this case), the included Linux is just an **embedded** version, so installation of extra packages would rather be difficult.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to try to see contents of a **binary** file. It's normal for udhcpd (from busybox) to store leases into binary file format.
`/tmp/dnsmasq.leases` is possibly maintained by `dnsmasq` and it is not related to busybox `udhcpd` in any ways.
You can use `dumpleases` command if DD-WRT provides it to present a clean contents of `udhcpd` binary file.